# Where'd the SlimDX NuGet package go?

Tags: slimdx

I've been working on a SlimDX project from a couple of different machines lately.  Today I went to pull down my code from SVN, and went through the dance of re-installing all the nuget packages referenced in the project, and I search for slimDX in Nuget, and nothing comes up.

Where'd the package go, and why was it taken down?  It's not that rough to install the SDK instead, but NuGet is more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

You can always just install the redistributable of slimdx, you don't need the entire sdk.